# Should I just disable UInteger type on JOOQ?

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I've been trying to write some queries (for MySQL) and I'm not sure how to write this particular one that involves Integer and UInteger types:

```
DSL.position(T1.FIELD, ":", -1).eq(T2.UINTFIELD)
```

`position` returns a `Field<Integer>`, so I can't simply compare this result to my `Field<UInteger>`. Is there a simple way to achieve it? I'd like to keep the correct field types for further validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`DSL.cast()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#cast-org.jooq.Field-org.jooq.DataType-) or [`DSL.coerce()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#coerce-org.jooq.Field-org.jooq.DataType-) for this. I recommend coerce.

- `DSL.cast()` produces a SQL cast expression and a jOOQ field reference of the desired type
- `DSL.coerce()` does not affect the generated SQL but still produces a jOOQ filed reference of the desired type.

For example:

```
position(T1.FIELD, ":", -1).eq(coerce(T2.UINTFIELD, SQLDataType.INTEGER))
```